# Как разместить/подключить Мускулы на GitHub?

Tags: javascript, mysql, github

Есть [сайт-портфолио](https://dgdays.github.io/) с разными моими проектами. Большая часть из них сделана от балды(т.к. только учусь), но есть и хорошие [пятнашки](https://dgdays.github.io/pyatnahi_moi/index.html), написанные лично мной. Хотел бы сделать таблицу рекордов. Для этого надо подключить MySQL к странице, но не знаю как это сделать на самом GitHub.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что делать?

Comment: На самом GitHub — никак, github.io позволяет хранить только статический контент без всяких баз и прочих бэкендов

Comment: @andreymal, обидно( Но, спасибо

Comment: Ну, api то можно прикрутить.. Пока сделаете так, что этим api кроме вас никто не сможет пользоваться - станете хорошим специалистом)

Comment: По поводу "хороших" пятнашек - вы же проверяете сгенерированную перестановку на разрешимость? =)

Comment: @vp_arth, для этого есть функция для запутывания) Она имитирует клик по полям из-за этого любую комбинацию в данных пятнашках можно распутать;) А про api модете подробнее? Что вы имели ввиду?

Comment: Где-то не на github делаете api, разрешаете ему CORS с вашего github.io и ходите туда выгружаете/собираете данные

Comment: @vp_arth, заманчивая идея Надо будет попробовать)